# how to join tables and get sum of first table if second has multiple occurences

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables "temp_user_batches" and "user_activities" i am trying to find sum of user_activities for users present in temp_user_batches table.

problem is sum of user_activities is getting multiplied by number of times in ratio of occurences of user in temp_user_batches table.

Below is temp_user_batches table

[image]

This is user_activities table

[image]

it is supposed to give sum of time_spent column `649 + 364` = `1013` but instead its giving `2016`

my query is:

```
SELECT temp_user_batches.user_id as user_id, 
       temp_user_batches.activity_goal as goal,
       DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 day) as min_activity_date, 
       CURDATE() as max_activity_date,
       (sum(user_activities.time_spent)/60) as total_time_spent
FROM temp_user_batches
INNER JOIN user_activities
   ON temp_user_batches.user_id = user_activities.user_id
WHERE activity_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 day) AND CURDATE()
group by user_id, goal, max_activity_date, min_activity_date
```

Comment: How many rows to you expect to get as output from the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a derived table that contains the `DISTINCT` pairs of `user_id, activity_goal` from table `temp_user_batches`:

```
SELECT t1.user_id as user_id, 
       t2.activity_goal as goal,
       DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 day) as min_activity_date, 
       CURDATE() as max_activity_date,
       (sum(t2.time_spent)/60) as total_time_spent
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT user_id, activity_goal
   FROM temp_user_batches) AS t1
INNER JOIN user_activities AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
WHERE activity_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 day) AND CURDATE()
group by user_id, goal, max_activity_date, min_activity_date
```

Comment: thanks @Girogos why it's hard to understand sql logics

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you should try to `GROUP_BY` the `temp_user_batches` on `user_id`, `last_activity` before joining it with `user_activities`. This is because now you join `user_activities` on 2 rows instead of 1 row the way you want (from what I understand).

Something like:

```
SELECT 
    temp_user_batches.user_id AS user_id,
    temp_user_batches.activity_goal AS goal,
    DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS min_activity_date,
    CURDATE() AS max_activity_date,
    (SUM(user_activities.time_spent) / 60) AS total_time_spent
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        temp_user_batches
    GROUP BY user_id , last_activity)
        INNER JOIN
    user_activities ON temp_user_batches.user_id = user_activities.user_id
WHERE
    activity_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY user_id , goal , max_activity_date , min_activity_date
```